# How can I use "vanishing point" to copy a texure from a plane to a flat image?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have a picture from a Bathroom where I want to textureize the tile.

I have mapped one of the walls in `Vanishing point filter` view, but how can I copy the wall out to a normal 2-dimensional plane so that I can use the texture with correct perspective?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how to do that in Photoshop, but the Open Source Software [Hugin](http://hugin.sourceforge.net/) lets you do just this. There is a tutorial [here](http://hugin.sourceforge.net/tutorials/perspective/en.shtml). You basically have to

1. Load your image into Hugin
2. Set the projection for the output to `rectilinear`.
3. Create some horizontal and some vertical control points (to teach Hugin what should become horizontal and what should become vertical lines)
4. Run `Optimize Positions, View and Barrel (y,p,r,v,b)`
5. Run `Stich now!` to export your image, which should now be a normal 2d plane as you wished.

Then you can open the resulting file in Photoshop and continue with texturizing...